# Solve: $dx/dt = x - xy$, $dy/dt = y - xy$ with $x(0)$ and $y(0)$ as initial condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve this system of coupled ODE: $$\frac{dx}{dt} = x - xy$$ and $$\frac{dy}{dt} = y - xy.$$

So by subtracting I get $$\frac{d(x-y)}{dt} = (x-y),$$ which then gives:

$$x(t) - y(t) = (x(0) - y(0))e^t.$$

But is there a way to solve for $x(t)$ and $y(t)$?

Comment: Continue with $y=x-Ae^t$ and you'll get $x'=x-x^2+Axe^t$, which can be solved by sequential substitions $x=e^u$, $u=t+v$, $w=e^{-v}$. Then you can get something like $w'=(1-Aw) e^t$, which can be solved by variables separation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can write $x(t) = y(t) + \alpha \exp(t)$, where $\alpha = x(0)−y(0)$. After substituting it into the second equation of system we get a Riccati equation $y'(t) = y(t) - (y(t) + \alpha \exp(t))y(t)$. Substituting $y(t) = (z(t))^{-1}$  leads into equation $z'(t) + z(t) (1-\alpha \exp(t)) = 1$ with the Cauchy condition $z(0) = (y(0))^{-1}$. So,
$$
z(t) = \exp\left(-\int\limits_{0}^{t} (1-\alpha \exp(\xi)) d\xi\right) \left(\frac{1}{y(0)}+\int\limits_{0}^{t} \exp\left(\int\limits_{0}^{\xi} (1-\alpha \exp(\eta)d\eta)\right) d\xi\right)=\\
=\frac{\exp(-\alpha -t) \left(\exp(\alpha \exp(t)) (\alpha +y(0))-\exp(\alpha)
   y(0)\right)}{\alpha y(0)}.
$$
And now we can obtain $y$:
$$
y(t) 
=\frac{y(0) \exp({t+x(0)}) (x(0)-y(0))}{x(0) \exp({\exp(t) (x(0)-y(0))+y(0)})-\exp(x(0)) y(0)}.
$$
And $x$ can be expressed as $x(t) = y(t) + (x(0)-y(0)) \exp(t)$.